# Cuda memory allocation

Tags: image-processing, memory-management, cuda, nvidia-jetson

I am working with jetson TX2. I capture images from camera, as `unsigned char *image`.

Then, I need to do some image processing. For that, I use the GPU. With the jetson TX2, we can avoid the transfer of data host/device and device/host because the RAM is shared between the GPU and the CPU. For that, I use :

```
int height = 6004 ;
int width = 7920 ;
int NumElement = height*width ;
unsigned char *img1 ;
cudaMallocManaged(&img1, NumElement*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Using that method, there is no limitation with the PCI. My problem is how assign the image from the buffer, to img1.
This method works, but it is too long :

```
for(int i =0 ; i<NumElement ; i++)
    img[i] = buffer[i] ;
```

I loose the advantage of the GPU using naive for loop ... And I if just use that method :

```
img = buffer
```

Like that, I have a problem when I enter in the kernel .

Answer (score 1):

Use `cudaMemcpy` with `cudaMemcpyDefault`, something like

```
cudaMemcpy(&buffer[0], &img[0], NumElement * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyDefault);
```

You could also potentially use `memcpy`